# strip_tags removes allowed tags when within attributes

Tags: php

For some reason, **PHP's strig_tags( ) function** is removing brackets from tags which are explicitly allowed, when those tags appear within an attribute.

*Example:*

```
<div data-contents="<p>Hello!</p>"></div>
```

*becomes*

```
<div data-contents="pHello!/p"></div>
```

I know, I know. This isn't necessarily good practice.

Regardless, any ideas?

Comment: You're right that embedding HTML into attribute values isn't necessarily good practice. So... why are you doing it anyways when there are countless better approaches? Just curious. And also, why are you using strip_tags in this case anyways?

Answer (score 2):

As the warnings on the [man page](http://php.net/strip_tags) state: `**Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.`

If you want to embed HTML inside an attribute, it must be properly encoded, e.g. you should have `&lt;p&gt;Hello!&lt;/p&gt;` instead.

Strip tags is "dumb" and will remove anything that LOOKS like a tag, regardless of where that tag occurs in the text, or if it would result in a broken page or not.

Comment: This exactly. If the reason you are using `strip_tags` is to not allow certain HTML in certain forms, then I'd rather suggest you use a library, like AntiSamy (not sure if there's a PHP port/equivalent)